# How to understand the name between PRIMARY KEY and '(' in MySQL table creation?

Tags: mysql

How to understand the name 'test_id' in sentence like this in MySQL?

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT, PRIMARY KEY test_id(id));
```

In the time learning MySQL, I happen to read a statement like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT, PRIMARY KEY test_id(id));
```

In my MACOS 10.14 mysql@5.7 shell, I've tried to omit the 'test_id' to create a table, I use 'DESC test;' statement, found no difference between the two table i created.

1. Statement with 'test_id':

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test(id INT, PRIMARY KEY test_id(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DESC test;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

2. Statement without 'test_id':

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test2(id INT, PRIMARY KEY (id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> DESC test2;
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id    | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Actually, add the prefixing is not my idea, as mentioned, i read it from a mysql tutorial sample. I tried, also found that make no sense to add the test_id. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#idm140466403465344) says is:

> The name of a `PRIMARY KEY` is always `PRIMARY`

Basically, MySQL is accepting the name (because it wants to be nice) and then silently discarding it (because you cannot set your own name after all). It's better spotted with this other example:

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE test(id INT, foo INT, PRIMARY KEY this_is_ignored (id), KEY this_is_kept (foo));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> show keys from test;
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test  |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id          | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          1 | this_is_kept |            1 | foo         | A         |           0 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+--------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

([Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t2gRFwi3YqHNeJf3nBJGaw/0)).

Answer (score 1):

Both the statements are doing the same job. They are creating the table. But in first SQL

```
CREATE TABLE test(id INT, PRIMARY KEY test_id(id))
```

it creates a table called test and gives the primary key constraint a name 'test_id'.

In case of the second SQL

```
CREATE TABLE test2(id INT, PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

it creates a table called test and generates a random name for primary key constraint.

Use below query and check the constraints created using both table

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
```